# Mongoid and counter_cache column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, counter-cache

I have Comment model:

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, touch: true#, counter_cache: true
```

When I run:

```
Article.first.comments.count => 1 #without counter_cache: true
```

but with "counter_cache: true" I get :

> Article.first.comments.count =>  NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
>   Article.first.comments =>  NoMethodError: undefined method`count' for nil:NilClass

Has anyone encountered such problem?

Answer (score 6):

The complete solution for future reference is:

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, touch: true, counter_cache: :comments_count
 end

class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :comments_count, type: Integer
end
```

So don't forget to add the integer field to the parent model.

Comment: Seems like `counter_cache: true` is not doing anything right with Mongoid so it's one of those key differences between AR and Mongoid that is badly documented in the official Rails doc.

Answer (score 2):

Sloved with:

> counter_cache: :comments_count

Answer (score 0):

As with ActiveRecord, the :counter_cache option can be used on an association to make finding the number of belonging objects more efficient. Also similar to ActiveRecord, you must take into account that there will be an extra attribute on the associated model. This means that with Mongoid, you need to include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic on the associated model

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/8.0/reference/associations/index.html#the-counter-cache-option